# Return text string and then call upon said string in later function

Tags: c++

I'm almost done with all my homework, but the last part I have to do is make a program that will read some values from a text file called "quad.txt" and calculate the roots with the quadratic formula and then output the values. The first part of the lab was do do this all in one function, main. That works fine. However, now I am asked to write three separate functions: one which calculates the discriminant (b^2 -(4*a*c)) and returns a string value (positive, zero, or negative) based on the value of the discriminant, another which will calculate the actual roots and output based on the returned string value above, and finally the main function which will open the file and run the two other functions. See my code below, but where I'm stuck is that I can't figure out how to return a string from function disc(), and then get the function display() to call upon the returned string value and output the correct data. Here is my code so far:

Here is the link to my quad.txt file [quad.txt](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?z3k77ytz3i1ikla)

```cpp
//Brian Tucker
//5.23.2012
//Lab 6 Part1
//Quadratic Formula from text file

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int a, b, c; //sets up vars
double r1, r2;

string disc(){
    if((pow(b,2) - (4*a*c) > 0)){ //determines if there are two roots and outputs
    return positive;
    }
    else if((pow(b,2) - (4*a*c) == 0)){ //determines if there is a double root
    return zero;
    }
    else if((pow(b,2) - (4*a*c) < 0)){ //determines if there are no roots
    return negative;
    }
}

void display(string data){
    r1=((-b)+sqrt(pow(b, 2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a); //quadratic formula
    r2=((-b)-sqrt(pow(b, 2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);

    if(positive){
    cout<<setw(3)<<"a="<<a; //outputting a, b, c
    cout<<setw(3)<<"b="<<b;
    cout<<setw(3)<<"c="<<c;
    cout<<setw(7)<<"2 rts";
    cout<<setw(5)<<"r1="<<r1;
    cout<<setw(5)<<"r2="<<r2;
    }
    else if(zero){
    cout<<setw(3)<<"a="<<a; //outputting a, b, c
    cout<<setw(3)<<"b="<<b;
    cout<<setw(3)<<"c="<<c;
    cout<<setw(7)<<"Dbl rt";
    cout<<setw(5)<<"r1="<<r1;
    }
    else if(negative){
    cout<<setw(3)<<"a="<<a; //outputting a, b, c
    cout<<setw(3)<<"b="<<b;
    cout<<setw(3)<<"c="<<c;
    cout<<setw(7)<<"No rts";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
    ifstream numFile; //sets up the file
    numFile.open("quad.txt"); //opens the file

    while(numFile.good()){ //while there are still values in the file, perform the function

    numFile>>a>>b>>c;

    string result = disc();
    display(result);
    }

    numFile.close();

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to return a std::string from disc, pass it as an argument into display, and compare it to the set values using ==.

For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string valueFunction( int i)
{ 
  if ( i >0 )
   return "positive";
  else
   return "not positive";
}

void resultFunction( std::string data)
{
   if (data == "positive")
      std::cout<<"It was a positive number"<<std::endl;
   else if (data == "not positive")
      std::cout<<"it was not a positive number"<< std::endl;
}

int main()
{  
   int i = 453;
   std::string result = valueFunction(i);
   resultFunction(result);
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but my professor listed this in the assignment sheet: "Create a function to calculate the discriminant and return the words: "positive", "zero" or "negative" based on the condition." What would you recommend I do to return a string value (is it even possible?)? What I'd prefer, instead of simply being told what to do, is to be pointed in a direction of where I can read and learn how to do this, since I'm still pretty new to C++.

Comment: @BrianTucker Return a std::string from disc(). Editing my answer(sorry, bad reading on my part).

Comment: Awesome. I'll give this a shot and then report back!

Comment: My god you're awesome! It works. Thank you so much! I had tried using a string() before but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Eeee I'm so happy!!!!! Thanks!!!!!!!! :)

Comment: Although I do have one issue. Though it works just fine, when I run it in CMD, for some reason it reads the last set of data values and outputs them twice. Any ideas on why this is the case? I only have 15 values in my txt file (5 sets of 3), however there are 6 lines being output, with the last line the same as the one preceding.

Comment: @BrianTucker  The reason why it prints out twice is that your check for failure(numFile.good() etc), is after the reading. Thus the last time through the loop, it tries to read, fails, then uses the same values.

Comment: I've tried adding `if(numFile.fail()){return 0;}` in a number of places in the code but it doesn't ever change the output. Any suggestions on what to do?